# How do you do Electro-mechanical Assembly Documentation?

Tags: assembly, packages, documentation, electro-mechanical

I realize this isn't specifically EE theory related, but I hope EE documentation advice falls within the scope of this forum!

For example, I have an enclosure from a mechanical engineer, and their mechanical assembly drawing.  We worked together to get a board outline, and I have my PCBA and my EE fab/assembly drawings.
I have some "off board" components - switches, buttons - that have wires to the board, and get inserted into the housing.

Historically, I would include a detailed assembly document with step-by-step instructions on wiring external components, how to program the firmware, etc, which would go to techs in production.

Since this company is more prototyping oriented (and I'm effectively the only EE), they'd prefer a more compact and concise drawing package that experienced engineers would be able to interpret and execute.
Something like this image, I imagine:
[Electro Mechanical Assembly](http://baknorthermal.com/packaging/electro-mechanical-assembly.php)

Specifically, what I'm asking is what do your drawing packages look like and how do you create them especially to capture that kind of assembly information - wiring an external switch to a PCB for example?
My personal goal is always to have an archivable package that someone new could pull down and recreate the product.  I tend to do it with photos and words, but I'm at a loss on how to do it with drawings (I need to improve my ME skills I think!)

I'd like to share some examples with the team so any comprehensive images or examples would be really helpful.

I've done a lot of reading, I've seen a lot of blog posts on important things to include and advertisements for software solutions - but I've had trouble finding examples of execution.

Any help or discussion would be really helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: If you buy a PCBA i.e. an electronic product comprising a PCB with components and connectors and mounting holes, what do you get re documentation? Pick the best and emulate that.

Comment: Mechanical assembly like you referenced, plus wiring list table in same drawing (maybe another sheet). Probably also want to show a diagram of wiring harness, else you will have no repeatability.

Comment: Sure, these are definitely elements I want to capture - do you have some examples?  "Wiring list table" are great words, but how does that get implemented?  Is it a schematic page, do I ask the mechs to draw it and capture it in their assembly drawings?